# Unable to duplicate JS variable for prebid slot

Tags: javascript, google-dfp, prebid.js

This code has to do with serving ads on my site. The top part is where each of the ad slots gets defined.  Then I have a function that will load any individual ad.  This function needs to pull the appropriate ad slot variable defined at the top, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var slot1;
googletag.cmd.push(function () {
    slot1 = googletag.defineSlot('/50970423/ffn-hb-rect-1', [[300, 250]], 'div-1')
        .addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
});
var slot2;
googletag.cmd.push(function () {
    slot2 = googletag.defineSlot('/50970423/ffn-hb-rect-ex', [[300, 250]], 'div-2')
        .addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
});

function refreshBid(adUnitName) {
    if (adUnitName == '/50970423/ffn-hb-rect-1') {
        var slot_to_load = slot1;
    }
    else if (adUnitName == '/50970423/ffn-hb-rect-ex') {
        var slot_to_load = slot2;
    }


    pbjs.que.push(function () {
        pbjs.requestBids({
            timeout: PREBID_TIMEOUT,
            adUnitCodes: [adUnitName],
            bidsBackHandler: function () {
                pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync([adUnitName]);
                googletag.pubads().refresh([slot_to_load]);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Thing is, if I change that line near the end to googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]); it will work perfectly (of course this only works for the first ad slot since it's hardcoded, so it's not a solution to the problem). Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the `slot_to_load` variable *inside* your if/else statement, so at that bottom line `slot_to_load` is `undefined`. Define the variable outside the if/else and then set its value within and your code will work:

```
function refreshBid(adUnitName) {
    var slot_to_load;
    if (adUnitName == '/50970423/ffn-hb-rect-1') {
        slot_to_load = slot1;
    }
    else if (adUnitName == '/50970423/ffn-hb-rect-ex') {
        slot_to_load = slot2;
    }


    pbjs.que.push(function () {
        pbjs.requestBids({
            timeout: PREBID_TIMEOUT,
            adUnitCodes: [adUnitName],
            bidsBackHandler: function () {
                pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync([adUnitName]);
                googletag.pubads().refresh([slot_to_load]);
            }
        });
    });

}
```